# Unable to deploy a Roo/GWT application on Google AppEngine from Springsource Tool Suite

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, spring-roo, springsource

I followed [this excellent tutorial](http://www.thescreencast.com/2010/05/how-to-gwt-roo.html) but, as it doensn't cover the deployment part, I tried to do it by myself.

So, I installed Springsource Tool Suite in Ubuntu.
Then, I create a "demo1" Roo project.
Next, with the built-in Roo Shell, I taped the following commands:

```
persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY 
entity --class ~.server.domain.Employee
field string --fieldName firstName --sizeMin 3 --sizeMax 20
field string --fieldName lastName --sizeMin 3 --sizeMax 20
gwt setup
```

After I checked "Use Google Webkit" in "Webkit Options", the project ran perfectly!
Then, to deploy the application to the App Engine, I taped the following command:

```
persistence setup –database GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE –provider DATANUCLEUS
```

which runs without any problem.
Then, i setup the AppEngine options (Application name and version ...) and clicked on the "Deploy App Engine Project" icon.

A popup shows and asks for the project name, email and password. 
I gave all these information and clicked on "Deploy".

Unhopefully, an error occured and a popup showed with the following error message:

```
GWT compilation failed
```

And in the console, I got the following error:

```
Compiling module com.springsource.demo1.gwt.ApplicationCommon
   [ERROR] Module has no entry points defined
```

I think that the problem is that GWT can't find the war file ...
Anyone succeded in deploying a GWT/Roo application by clicking on the "Deploy" icon?

Thank you very much,

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is go to the Google -> Webtool Kit Settings... and remove `ApplicationCommon` from the `Entry Point Modules` list, and you probably need to remove some more, so only the configuration file with the Entry point remains.

Some background: The error is generated by the GWT compiler. When deploying GWT compiles the Java source to JavaScript. GWT uses module files with the extension: `.gwt.xml` which contain configuration information for the compiler. In at least one of these configuration files an entry point must be specified. By default the Webtool Kit Settings contain all those gwt.xml files from your project (there are probably 4), while only those with an entry point should be specified.

Answer (score 0):

What version of STS were you using?  I think this may be fixed with STS 2.3.3.M2...

Comment: I installed the following version: springsource-tool-suite-2.3.3.M2-e3.6-linux.